# How to work around circular dependency in databases?

Tags: database, sql-server-2008, entity-framework-5

Two tables (Post and Thread) in my database refer to one another which is suppose to be a solution for SQL server not supporting 1-to-1 relationships. See [diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVdzL.png) . I made key_post not accept null values in my first Database, but that meant that I couldn't insert into either tables so I had to make key_post nullable to at least be able to create the thread first before filing the key_post field and I can set key_post to null if I wanted to remove that post , but I wanted to find a solution that doesn't require special attention in code because it can get messy.

Comment: i dont think it makes sense to have a key post attribute in your thread table. instead, your post table should have a thread_ID that is a foreign key for thread table's ID, and that is how the two should be linked, right?

Comment: @cptwonton Posts has the in_thread attribute to determine what thread they belong to. The attribute key_post in table Thread covers a different issue which is that each thread needs to be linked to a post at creation, this is how it is specified for the application that I'm building, it's suppose to be a 1-to-1 relationship but true 1-to-1 relationships can't really be implemented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entity Framework isn't going to allow this to happen unless one is null.  That is because it is going to insert one first and with the FK there, it'll fail.  You can either make 1 null like you are doing and be forced to do it this way or you need to create a "ThreadPost" table that would be defined as:

```
ThreadPost

ThreadId (PK)
PostId (PK)
```

Then you'd remove the ThreadId from Post and PostId from Thread.  Technically, I believe EF will design tables this way if you use code first automatically.